# Super Anagram Solution AOK?

Tags: python, super, anagram

I am trying to create a program to identify 'super anagrams' i.e anagrams that have the same first and last letters. I came up with this, and it works, but I've got this feeling that there's a cleaner way to do it.

```
words = input('Enter words: ')
listed = words.split() 
first = listed[0] 
second = listed[1] 
first_split = (list(first))
second_split = (list(second)) 
if first_split[0]==second_split[0] and first_split[-1]==second_split[-1]:
  first_split_alpha = sorted(first_split)
  second_split_alpha = sorted(second_split) 
  if first_split_alpha == second_split_alpha:
    print('Super Anagram!')
  else: print('Huh?')
else: print('Huh?')
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't ask a specific programming question. Perhaps http://codereview.stackexchange.com might be a better forum.

Answer (score 1):

1) The temporary variable `listed` is unnecessary. Use tuple unpacking to get the values

2) The use of `list` is unnecessary. `str` is an iterable object, too.

3) The use of `_alpha` is unecessary. Just use `sorted(foo)` in your expression.

```
a,b = input('Enter words: ').split()

if sorted(a) == sorted(b) and a[0] == b[0] and a[-1] == b[-1]:
  print('Super Anagram!')
else:
  print('Huh?')
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion I would make would be to check that the input contains exactly two words. Your code would throw an exception if the user were to enter just one word. You might do this by:

```
words = [] # empty list
while len(words) != 2:
    words = input('Enter two words: ').split()
```

Following that, you could reduce the number of distinct variables you create. If you create a variable and then only use it once, chances are that you could inline whatever you are doing with that variable:

```
first = words[0]
second = words[1]
if (first[0] == second[0] and 
    first[-1] == second[-1] and 
    sorted(first) == sorted(second)):
    print('Super Anagram!')
else:
    print('Huh?')
```